# Does the bending air on a wing create one or multiple vortices?

Tags: aerodynamics, vortex

As explained in the first paragraph of [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/102049/70478) answer, air will bend inwards on the top of the wing, and outwards on the bottom of the wing. This creates an inward flow component on the top of the wing and a outwards component on the bottom. I'm pretty sure this would create vortices/vortex once the wing has passed. It sounds like what I'm saying might be hard to understand, so maybe try to visualize the flows I was talking about.

So my main question is this : Would this bending of air on the surfaces make one big vortex or multiple smaller ones once the wing has passed? The picture on [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/102030/70478) answer might help convey what I mean by air bending on the upper and lower surfaces.

Also, how would tip vortices change this, since they contribute to these spanwise flows?

(If that doesn't make sense, I will happily clarify in the comments and edit this question if needed)

Comment: You have already got [a very good answer to the present question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/102030/64684) in another similar question of yours: do you actually read the answers that you get?

Comment: @sophit yeah I recalled reading that answer, but it doesn’t really state anything about how many vortices are created along the wings trailing edge.

Comment: How would you count a distributed vortex?

Comment: One might imagine one giant vortex rolling off the back of a straight wing like a carpet, and more vorticies off a swept wing.  A highly swept wing may have fewer, larger vorticies, but more *parallel* rather than *perpendicular* to the fuselage.

Comment: I personally like [the picture used on Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/Aircraft_wing_lift_distribution_showing_trailing_vortices_%283%29.svg). It explains in a simple way where the vortices form and how the coalesce into the tip vortices.

Comment: @sophit oh okay, so the vortices I was talking about combine into the tip vortices? Neat.

Comment: Yes, small vortices coalesce.  Just like small individual thermals below roughly 500 ft AGL coalesce into ones big enough for sailplanes to circle in.